# How to get they are isomorphic iff $\nu_{eAe}$ inner?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I am reading the paper "Morita algebras", the link is here:http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869313001002

On page 194, there is a place I don't know: [image: the place marked green]

Can anyone help me get the place marked green? Thank you!(Here $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field k. An idempotent $e$ of $A$ is called self-dual provided the left $A$-module $D(eA)$ is isomorphic to  $Ae$. By lemma 2.4, $eAe$ is a Frobenius algebra, $\nu_{eAe}$ is a Nakayama automorphism of the Frobenius algebra $eAe$.)

Comment: Could you also give the full assumption on $A$ and recall the definition of a self-dual idempotent?

Comment: @Hanno I have added those things, sir.